# Rust - How to implement default constructor for struct holding closure

Tags: rust

I would like to make a struct holding a closure.

Also there should be a way to make kind 'default' value of the struct type which is holding no or void computation.

Here is my attempt;

```rust
struct Computation<X, Y, F>
where
    F: Fn(&X) -> Y,
{
    f: F,
    _p: PhantomData<(X, Y)>,
}

impl<X, Y, F> Computation<X, Y, F>
where
    F: Fn(&X) -> Y,
{
    fn new(f: F) -> Self {
        Computation {
            f: f,
            _p: PhantomData,
        }
    }

    fn default() -> Self {
        Computation::new(|&_|()) // <- ERROR
    }
}
```

And here is the compiler output.

```
mismatched types
expected type parameter `F`
          found closure `[closure@src/lib.rs:212:26: 212:30]`
every closure has a distinct type and so could not always match the caller-chosen type of parameter `F`rustcClick for full compiler diagnostic
lib.rs(200, 12): this type parameter
lib.rs(212, 9): arguments to this function are incorrect
lib.rs(204, 8): associated function defined here
```

It seems that trying to specifying the concrete type of F 'after the call` if default is the problem. Then, is there any way to implement 'default constructor' for these kind of structs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't know the type of a closure in advance. However, if your closure doesn't, well, close around any variables, then it can be converted to a function pointer type `fn(&X) -> Y` (Note the lowercase "f"). Consider

```
impl<X> Computation<X, (), fn(&X) -> ()> {
  fn default() -> Self {
    Computation::new(|_| ())
  }
}
```

Note that this goes in a *separate* `impl` block from your `new` function, which is parameterized by all three of `X`, `Y`, and `F`. This `impl`, on the other hand, is only available when `Y` is `()` and `F` is `fn(&X) -> ()` (the type of function pointers from `&X` to `()`).

Also, since you're calling this function `default`, you may as well go all the way and let it be a true [`Default`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/default/trait.Default.html) value.

```
impl<X> Default for Computation<X, (), fn(&X) -> ()> {
  fn default() -> Self {
    Computation::new(|_| ())
  }
}
```

Note that we can only know the type in advance because we don't close around any variables. `fn(&X) -> Y` is the type of function pointers, which includes both top-level functions and closures that don't actually close (which are compiled to top-level functions internally). `fn(&X) -> Y` implements `Fn(&X) -> Y`, but so do a lot of other nontrivial closures, so not every closure is convertible to `fn(&X) -> Y`. `|_| ()` simply is because it doesn't use any variables from the enclosing scope.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can’t produce a value of an arbitrary type `F`. Things you could do to progress include making it optional:

```
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct Computation<X, Y, F>
where
    F: Fn(&X) -> Y,
{
    f: Option<F>,
    _p: PhantomData<fn(X) -> Y>,
}

impl<X, Y, F> Computation<X, Y, F>
where
    F: Fn(&X) -> Y,
{
    pub fn new(f: F) -> Self {
        Self {
            f: Some(f),
            _p: PhantomData,
        }
    }

    pub fn apply(&self, x: &X) -> Y {
        match &self.f {
            Some(f) => f(x),
            None => todo!(),
        }
    }
}
```

or using dynamic dispatch:

```
pub struct Computation<'a, X, Y> {
    f: Box<dyn Fn(&X) -> Y + 'a>,
}

impl<'a, X, Y> Computation<'a, X, Y> {
    pub fn new(f: impl Fn(&X) -> Y + 'a) -> Self {
        Self {
            f: Box::new(f),
        }
    }

    pub fn apply(&self, x: &X) -> Y {
        (self.f)(x)
    }
}

impl<'a, X, Y> Default for Computation<'a, X, Y> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self::new(|_| todo!())
    }
}
```

As you can see from the `todo!()`, the next problem you run into is that you can’t get a value of an arbitrary type `Y`. You could fix that by constraining the type to be default-constructible and using `Default::default()`, among other things.